# Program will not print the statement

Tags: java, methods

I have a program where i select an option to add ship, which prompts me to give an id e.g b 2. it then prompts me to enter a capacity. However, I am using a search method to prevent any repeat id's that I may enter a second time round. The program compiles, but my statement "Ship id is already in use" won't print out. Any ideas please?

Here is my code.

```
public int search(String id)
{
    for(int index = 0; index < ships.length && ships[index] != null; ++index)
    {
        shipId = id;
        if (ships[index].getId().equals(id))
        {
            return index;
        }
    }
    //ship id not found so you can add ship
    return -1;
}

public void addShip( )
{
    System.out.println("Enter ship id >> ");
    String id = kb.nextLine();
    if(id.equals(search(id)))
    {
        System.out.println("Ship id already in use");
        return;
    }


    else
    {
        //for(int i = 0; i < ships.length; ++i)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter ship capacity");
            int capacity = kb.nextInt();
            ships[shipCounter++] = new Ship(id, capacity);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my ship class:

```
public class Ship
{
    private String id;
    private int capacity;
    private int currentCrew; // index into the Crew array
                             // points to the next free space
                             // in the Crew array
    private String status;

    private Crew [ ] crew;

    public Ship(String id, int capacity)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.currentCrew = 0;
        crew = new Crew[capacity];

    }
    public Ship(String id, int capacity, String status)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.status = "available";
        this.currentCrew = 0;
        crew = new Crew[capacity];

    }
    public void setId(String newId)
    {
        id = newId;
    }
    public void setCapacity(int newCapacity)
    {
        capacity = newCapacity;
    }
    public void setStatus(String newStatus)
    {
        if(status.equals("available"))
        {
            newStatus = "on station";
            status = newStatus;
        }
        else if(status.equals("on station"))
        {
            newStatus = "maintenance";
            status = newStatus;
        }
        else if(status.equals("station") || status.equals("maintenance"))
        {
            newStatus = "available";
            status = newStatus;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid status");
        }
    }
    public String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
    public String getStatus()
    {
        return status;
    }
    public int getCapacity()
    {
        return capacity;
    }
    public int getCurrentCrew()
    {
        return currentCrew;
    }
    public void addCrew()
    {
        //if(currentCrew < capacity)
        {
            //System.out.println("Enter crew id >> ");
            //String id = kb.nextLine();
        }
    }

    public String toString()
    {

        String sdesc = 
         '\n'
        + "Ship"
        + '\n'
        + "["
        + '\n'
        + " "
        + "Id: " + id
        + " capacity: " + capacity
        + " current crew: " + currentCrew
        + " status: " + status
        + '\n'
        + "]";

        return sdesc;
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown enough of your code.  Show where `ships` is declared and any other code that initializes it.

Comment: You're comparing int with String...

Comment: Also, show how `Ship` class is defined. I guess that Ship.id is defined as Integer or int and you are checking it against a `String id` just a guess.

Answer (score 2):

Did you noticed this line

```
 if(id.equals(search(id)))
```

id is String type, but `search` return type is int.

if you see in `String` class `equals` method,

```
 if (anObject instanceof String) {

 }
 return false;
```

so its simply give false always

so the simple solution is convert that int to String.
something like

```
if(id.equals(search(id+"")))
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really understand the last part of
    if(id.equals(search(id+"")))

Comment: in java string + operator is play coordination operation. If you use String + Any object, the that object toString() will gets call. In this case we have wrapper Integer class for int, so the Integer class toString will gets call and we can get the appropriate String. i.e int 2 -> String 2

Comment: I don't think that is the correct usage of the search method. It returns an index, not the id

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to see if you already have a ship with the id, you should check that the index exists, which is what your search method returns.

```
 if(search(id) > 0)
 {
      System.out.println("Ship id already in use");
      return;
 }
```

Comment: I tried this but nothing changed when i ran the program ):

Comment: Well, that is the correct usage of that method, so you might want to learn how to set breakpoints in your code and use a debugger. You haven't shown in your question where `Ship[] ships` is declared, so I can't help more than this